# how to set QProgressBar chunk to not go out Progress Bar layout

Tags: qt

When setting progress bar border as rounded I'm facing a problem which resumes by having a squared chunk which go out of the progress bar space and when setting style for chunk to be rounded it disappears.

progress bar shape:

[image]

progress bar with value:

[image]

Comment: You did not show up your code, but it seems that you need to use `clip: true` property.

Comment: `
QProgressBar{
 border-radius: 15px;
}

QProgressBar::chunk{
 border-radius: 15px;
}
`
This is my code. I tried your suggestion but didn't work @AlexanderDYagilev

Comment: Ah, I thought you are using QML... I never used Widgets. Maybe it's a bug, and as a workaround you can try using 2 separate controls: circle with clip enabled (if widgets supports clipping) and a progress bar as a child of this circle.